# Can not get GPS current location when open the app with off GPS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I have a web view android app that using google map current location to get user location, when user click on an icon I am calling a native function to access the gps, the issue is when open the app with offline GPS, then click on icon it will ask to on the gps and when press ok nothing will happen, even click on the icon again still nothing will happen unless close the app and open again then it will work, please help it really made me get crazy...

```
public void location_request()

{
    final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                   //The client can initialize location
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied.
                    try {

                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you added proper permissons?

Comment: yeah it does not have permission issue because if the GPS be on or refresh the page then it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to enable GPS and make sure location permission is given. Initially when GPS is disabled then onFailureListener will trigger and popup GPS enable dialog but after pressing ok it will not trigger onSuccessListener so you need to make current location request from onActivityResult but if GPS is enabled before entering the app then onSuccessListener will trigger and u can request for current location from there.

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(HomeActivity.this);
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            task.addOnSuccessListener(HomeActivity.this, locationSettingsResponse -> {
                // Make your current location request here

            });

            task.addOnFailureListener(HomeActivity.this, e -> {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(HomeActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                }
            });


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            // Make your current location request here
        }
    }
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings

Comment: I am getting this error when replace your code instead of mine: Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level

Comment: I searched and found solution for previous error but the @Override location is wrong it giving this error: Annotations are not allowed here

Comment: Are you overriding onActivityResult method inside your location_request() method?